# How to hand over Boolean operator as parameter in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have a function which has quite a lot lines. In that function I have a `.filter{}` like:

```
fun getMyListForFoo(): List<Blub> {
  //.. lot of lines
  return myRepo.queryList()
    .filter{ it.flag == Query.IS_FOO }
    .map{ 
       //..mappings 
    }
}
```

and then I have a second function just to retrieve queries which are NOT `Foo`:

```
fun getMyListForNotFoo(): List<Blub> {
  //.. lot of lines
  return myRepo.queryList()
    .filter{ it.flag != Query.IS_FOO }
    .map{ 
       //..mappings 
    }
}
```

As you can the only difference is the `==` or `!=` operator in the `.filter` function. Although I have all the previous lines duplicated..

I bet there is a nice Kotlin way to enhance this code?

Comment: Adding to already provided answer, if you often need to get both the list of foo and list of not foo, then note there is a `partition()` function that creates both lists at the same time.

Answer (score 7):

Pass a predicate as a parameter to your function for filtering the list.

```kotlin
fun getMyList(predicate: (YourType) -> Boolean): List<Blub> {
  //.. lot of lines
  return myRepo.queryList()
    .filter(predicate)
    .map{ 
       //..mappings 
    }
}
```

Usage:

```kotlin
val listForFoo = getMyList { it.flag == Query.IS_FOO }
val listForNotFoo = getMyList { it.flag != Query.IS_FOO }
```

OR, if you just want to pass a Boolean, you can also do that:

```kotlin
fun getMyList(filterFoo: Boolean): List<Blub> {
  //.. lot of lines
  return myRepo.queryList()
    .filter { 
        val isFoo = it.flag == Query.IS_FOO
        if(filterFoo) isFoo else !isFoo
    }
    .map{ 
       //..mappings 
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted `filter { if (filterFoo) it.flag == Query.IS_FOO else it.flag != Query.IS_FOO }`

Comment: ok... so it was misleading to me... either you do `filterFoo` or you don't... "don't" doesn't necessarily mean do the opposite... but maybe that's more regarding naming than the rest... I think in that specific case the first solution is way more clear than the second one...

Comment: `if(filterFoo) isFoo else !isFoo` could be simplified to `filterFoo == isFoo`

Comment: @Tenfour04 yeah. All that can be replaced by `filterFoo == (it.flag == Query.IS_FOO)`. I didn't do that as that might get harder to understand.

Answer (score 4):

I would use `partition` directly.

I created [a sample in kotlinlang.org's playground](https://pl.kotl.in/ZGLaxQZb4) and it looks like this:

```
// Given a "thing"
data class Thing(val id: Int, val isFoo: Boolean)

// Have a function that simplifies this: 
fun filterThings(source: List<Thing>) = source.partition { it.isFoo }

// Alternatively, you could have a more generic one:
fun filterThings(source: List<Thing>, 
                 predicate: ((Thing) -> Boolean)) = source.partition(predicate)

// And you can use either like so:
// Given the source
val source = listOf(Thing(1, true), 
                    Thing(2, true), 
                    Thing(3, false), 
                    Thing(4, true), 
                    Thing(5, false), 
                    Thing(6, false))

// Filter them with the non-configurable version:
val results = filterThings(source)

// or the more configurable one where *you* supply the predicate:
val results = filterThings(source) { it.isFoo }
```

The results are going to be:

`results.first` is going to be the one that *pass* the predicate, and the rest will be in `results.second`:

```
results.first = [Thing(id=1, isFoo=true), Thing(id=2, isFoo=true), Thing(id=4, isFoo=true)]
results.second = [Thing(id=3, isFoo=false), Thing(id=5, isFoo=false), Thing(id=6, isFoo=false)]
```

Comment: Alternatively, instead of using `.first` and `.second` you might prefer the destructuring syntax: `val (myListForFoo, myListForNotFoo) = ...`